# Lisp: How to write an if statement with multiple conditions?

Tags: lisp

I understand how to write an if statement with an individual condition. For example:

```
(if (> a 20))
```

However, after researching online, I found no resources explaining how to write an if statement with multiple conditions (for example, checking if `a > 20` or `a < 10`). How do I write an if statement with multiple conditions in Lisp?

Comment: Take a look at `cond` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The if special form is the same no matter what:

```
(if test-expression 
    true-expression
    false-expression)
```

If you want something to happen if both `a` is above `20` or below `10` you just do:

```
(if (not (<= 10 a 20)) ; same as (or (> 20 a) (< 10 a))
    true-expression
    false-expression)
```

But I get it. What if you have two expressions where one of them true should trigger, then you can use `or`:

```
(if (or (> 20 a) (< 10 a))
    true-expression
    false-expression)
```

Now `and` and `or` are macros for nexted ifs. Eg. The expression above can be done like this:

```
(if (> 20 a)
    true-expression
    (if (< 10 a)
        true-expression
        false-expression)))
```

Where `true-expression` is the same expression both places.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `OR` and/or `AND` macros to combine conditions.

```
(if (or (> a 20) (< a 10))
 ;; do something
)
```